# What property holds a value for jquery droppable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a functionality with droppable/draggable where if both droppable divs have an element dropped in something happens.

```
var dropbox = $('#dropbox').val();
        var dropbox1 = $('#dropbox1').val();
    if(dropbox && dropbox1 != ''){
        $.post("account_main.php", 
          {data: $(this).text()}, 
          function(data) {
               alert("Works.");
          });       
        }
```

As seen [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/176/) nothing happens and there are no errors. I would like to get an explanation on why this did not work and also would be grateful to understand what would work. Any random tips would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the content of your dropboxes.
.`val()` is used to get the values of form elements.